Advice Needed for Cabinet Design and Door Hinges
I want to design a new cabinet and would appreciate your expert advice on the following points:

I plan to use full overlay concealed hinges for all doors (A, B, C, and D).
Each door will open to the right.
I've set half the beam thickness for doors B, C, and D.

What should be the minimum gap between the doors to ensure smooth operation?


Usually about 1/4". Split it to 1/8" space around each door. Did you check with the manufacturer of the hinges?

Note that if the front panels are solid wood oriented vertically, you may need to adjust the gaps to allow for expansion of the panels.

Kudos for the well-asked Question, but unfortunately the answer is: it depends.
Really the one and only place you'll get a definitive answer in advance is from a manufacturer; although of course for a known hinge you can get input from existing users in a suitable venue, the gapping someone else uses might not be down to spec but is instead based on another factor or factors (including their personal aesthetics, and simple ease-of-installation).
In the absence of the above then you'll need to find out empirically — that is, make some sort of simple mockup from scraps and find out how much clearance is actually needed, then proceed accordingly.
The issue is that "full-overlay concealed hinges" are not a single entity, that's merely a description of what they are and the function they provide. There are of course many similar hinges, but subtle differences between them could make enough difference that a stock answer – especially for minimum gap – wouldn't work for both cases; it only takes around 0.2mm / 0.008" to cause some binding.
